# Listview item swipe to reveal more options

Tags: flutter, listview, dart

Am trying to achieve this type of `listView` item in flutter but am stuck on what to do? It basically shows more actions when swiped to the left. I tried using an horizontal scroll but not working as expected. Can I be pointed in the right direction?[image]

Comment: Check this package : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install this package [flutter_slidable 0.5.7](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_slidable)

then just use it like that, it will be much easier and save much time than making it by yourself

```
import 'package:flutter_slidable/flutter_slidable.dart';
Slidable(
  actionPane: SlidableDrawerActionPane(),
  actionExtentRatio: 0.25,
  child: Container(
    color: Colors.white,
    child: ListTile(
      leading: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.indigoAccent,
        child: Text('$3'),
        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      title: Text('Tile n°$3'),
      subtitle: Text('SlidableDrawerDelegate'),
    ),
  ),
  actions: <Widget>[
    IconSlideAction(
      caption: 'Edit',
      color: Colors.blue,
      icon: Icons.archive,
      onTap: () => _showSnackBar('Archive'),
    ),
    IconSlideAction(
      caption: 'Activate',
      color: Colors.indigo,
      icon: Icons.share,
      onTap: () => _showSnackBar('Share'),
    ),
  ],
  secondaryActions: <Widget>[
    IconSlideAction(
      caption: 'More',
      color: Colors.black45,
      icon: Icons.more_horiz,
      onTap: () => _showSnackBar('More'),
    ),
    IconSlideAction(
      caption: 'Delete',
      color: Colors.red,
      icon: Icons.delete,
      onTap: () => _showSnackBar('Delete'),
    ),
  ],
);
```